# EEXIST 17 error while installing opencv using conda on windows

Tags: opencv, conda

I am trying to install opencv using conda on a windows machine. I am running the following command:

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv
```

and getting the following error:

```
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##
environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2

added / updated specs:
- opencv

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:
opencv: 2.4.11-py27_1 menpo

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: - WARNING conda.gateways.disk:exp_backoff_fn(49): 
Uncaught backoff with errno EEXIST 17
failed

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while installing 
package 'None'.

IOError(13, 'Permission denied')

Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done
IOError(13, 'Permission denied')
WindowsError(183, 'Cannot create a file when that file already exists')
```

Other people seem to have similar problems (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/4393). One of the solutions I found was to downgrade conda. I am currently using `conda 4.5.4` and when I try to downgrade using `conda install conda=4.2` I get the following error:

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
    conda:       4.5.4-py27_0  --> 4.2.16-py27_0
    conda-build: 3.10.5-py27_0 --> 3.9.2-py27_0
Proceed ([y]/n)? y
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling 
package 'defaults::conda-build-3.10.5-py27_0'.
WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied')

Attempting to roll back.
Rolling back transaction: done

WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied')
```

Regarding this issue I found the following similar posts:

[conda update conda permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181799/conda-update-conda-permission-error)

[Anaconda : Update conda failed because permission error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036662/anaconda-update-conda-failed-because-permission-error)

But the solutions given do not fix my problem.

Comment: It could be that your issue is related to this one (problems due with emptying CONDA_TRASH) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653630/warning-conda-gateways-diskexp-backoff-fn47-uncaught-backoff-with-errno-41

I had a similar error to you and I ended up solving it by creating a new environment and installing the package I wanted (`py-xgboost`) there instead.

Comment: Hi, I had to create a new environment too, and it worked

Comment: Glad to have helped! @robt

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem with installation and usage of the `OpenCV` library. If you have such а problem, you can try:

1. uninstall `opencv` with: `conda remove --yes opencv` (in case you have an installation but it does not work properly)
2. install `OpenCV` through pip: `pip install opencv-python`

I think this is a problem with `opencv` that comes from `Anaconda` channels. I came across this problem four months ago. Тhe problem may be resolved right now.

Answer (score 0):

**My guess is that you did not run this command with administrator privileges！**